# In Express.js how can we make res.send to wait for data to be fetched from database

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

The method `res.send()` returns (empty) before the data is fetched from database (Mongodb) from the method

```
 Skills.find({ skillbranch: branches[i]._id }, function (err, skills) {
```

How can we add await or async to this before returning?

I'm learning node/express and was not able to make up the syntax to use with some answers/examples on other posts on stackoverflow where they were using `async` , `await`, `Promise`.

```
const Skills = require('../models/skills.model.js');
const SkillBranch = require('../models/skillbranch.model.js');

exports.getSkills = function (req, res) {
   let branchSkills = [];       

   SkillBranch.find(function (err, branches) {         
     if (branches) {
        var obj = {
            "status": "200",
            "message": "skills",
            "data": branches
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < branches.length; i++) {                
            Skills.find({ skillbranch: branches[i]._id }, function (err, skills) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(skills)); //this is returning after res.send()
                branchSkills.push(skills);                                        
            })

            if (i == branches.length - 1) {                    
                var obj = {
                    "status": "200",
                    "message": "skills",
                    "data": branchSkills
                }

                //this is returning before Skills.find() is complete
                res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
            }
         }
     } else {
        var obj = {
            "status": "500",
            "message": "Getting skills ",
            "data": []
        }
        res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
     }
  })
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** call `res.send()` inside the `Skills.find()` callback, not outside it. But since you are calling multiple `Skills.find()` you need to keep track of how many callbacks have returned. For this you can use a variable:

```
// Keep track of completed find():
var completed = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < branches.length; i++) {                
    Skills.find({ skillbranch: branches[i]._id }, function (err, skills) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(skills));
        completed++;
        branchSkills.push(skills);

        if (completed == branches.length) {
            var obj = {
                "status": "200",
                "message": "skills",
                "data": branchSkills
            }
            res.send(JSON.stringify(obj)); // INSIDE callback
        }
    }) // <--- note that callback ends here!
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work.

Create a promise on the mongo call. Once it completes, just convert it to an array, push it to your branch skills, and resolve the promise with your new updated version. Then send data with that new updated version rather than your global branchSkills object you've been using.

Should be noted i'm not sure what you're using branch skills for, but you may just be able to resolve with `skills` without pushing to that global array? This should fix your timing issues though.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Skills.find({ skillbranch: branches[i]._id }).toArray((err, skills) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        branchSkills.push(skills);
        resolve(branchSkills);
      }          
    });
  });
}).then(updatedBranchSkills => {
  if (i == branches.length - 1) {                    
    var obj = {
      "status": "200",
      "message": "skills",
      "data": updatedBranchSkills
  }

  res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

Comment: Don't use `i` to track which promise has completed. Because this is asynchronous the second promise can finish last and you will end up calling `res.send()` early. If you are using promises use `Promise.all()` instead